# What's the short for "Євген"?

Tags: власні-назви

In Russian the name `Евгений` is shortened to `Женя` and I've just realized that I'm not aware of the similar short form for Ukrainian `Євген` - can we, for instance, treat as such `Женьо`? Or is there some another form possible?

UPD: As @Artemix pointed there are some versions mentioned in Wikipedia, the thing is I hadn't heard any of them in real life - so I actually don't know which of them is used more frequently de-facto and which just listed there for the sake of keeping list complete.

Comment: Є стаття у Вікіпедії, може щось там здайдете - [Євген](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD): "Євген, церковне Євгеній, народна форма: Югин, Ґєник, Ґеньо, Ґеник, Геник. Пестливі — Євгенко, Євгенчик. Розмовні форми: Женя, Женькo, Женьчик, Жекон, Жека, Женьо, Женьок та інші".

Comment: @shabunc I have heard in real life these forms: Євгенко, Євгенчик, Женя, Женькo, Женьчик, Жека, Женьо, Женьок

Comment: For me, Ukrainian names have not short name, if even they have one root. In examples above, most of them are just forms of passion by suffix. And we don’t have tradition change names from other countries.

Comment: @Follower, I disagree. While some of short name forms were borrowed from Russian or at least look like there were, but there's some about of short names that certainly aren't borrowed from Russian, and aren't suffix-based either. E.g.: _Мотря_, _Катря_, _Христя_.

Comment: I can point to example pairs as *Олександр – Олесь*. They have the same root but *Олесь* is a single name. And if take suffix-based, then *Євген* is already short form for *Євгеній*, so *Саша*, *Женя* and *Ґеник* are dialectical and single forms of this name.

Comment: @Follower, do you try to claim that _Олесь_ (_Лесь_) is a different name than _Олександр_? But, in fact, it depends: many people known as _Олесь/Лесь_ (e.g. [Олесь Гончар](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гончар_Олесь_Терентійович), [Лесь Подерев'янський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лесь_Подерв'янський)) are in-born _Олександр_'es. It is common situation when interpretation of _X_ and _Y_ as same name or as two different names varies from person to person (another example is Russian _Егор_, which was originally short of _Георгий_, but then became a distinct name). Or did I understand you argument wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Же́ня**:

  Examples:

  - [Vsevolod Nestayko](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vsevolod_Nestayko), “‘Барабашка’ ховається під землею”, 1992:

    > У житті *Жені* Киселя сталася несподівана, прямо-таки фантастична зміна.

  <sub>I don't provide more examples, because it's obvious that «Женя» is widely used (though it's not obvious whether it can be considered as an Russianism or no).</sub>
- **Же́ка**:

  Examples:

  - Rostyslav Sambuk, “Скіфська чаша”, 1981:

    > Але *Жека* не затримався — з’явився за три — чотири хвилини, вийшов з потоку пасажирів і одразу побачив дівчат.

  <sub>I don't provide more examples, because it's obvious that «Женя» is widely used (though it's not obvious whether it can be considered as an Russianism or no).</sub>
- **Геник**/**Ґеник** (mostly Western Ukrainian):

  Examples:

  - Natalka Smotrych (Shevchenko), “Бранці мороку”, 2007:

    > Ти не питаєш, хто такий *Женька*?.. <…> А *Євген*... він вважав те, що я вмію ворожити, страшенно захопливим. <…> *Геник* збожеволів від жаху, з мого дому його забрала «швидка», а за рік він наклав на себе руки в психушці. [Всі три реченні про одну й ту саму людину.]
  - Larysa Chahrovska, Natalka Smotrych (Shevchenko), “Афера на віллі”, 2008:

    > …*Геник*, в миру — *Євген* Васильович Горенко, власник і директор юридичної компанії «Консул», стягнув із плеча Яни сумку, вдав, що зважує її на правиці, крекнув і застогнав, імітуючи жах та надзвичайне перенапруження.

  <sub>There are also novels where *Геник* or *Ґеник* is used as short for *Генадій* (*Гена*), or where full name never appears (so it's unclear whether it's really *Євген*, *Генадій* or a distinct name). Notably, [“Музей покинутих секретів”](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Museum_of_Abandoned_Secrets) (2009) of Oksana Zabuzhko spells it as *Ґеник*.</sub>
- **Геньо**/**Ґеньо** (mostly Western Ukrainian):

  Examples:

  - The prominent example is Yevhen Ozarkevych, a Ukrainian doctor (1861 — 1916; see [in Ukrainian Wikipedia](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)), who is often referred to as *Геньо* in the Ukrainian-translated version of the dairy of the well-known Ukrainian writer [Olha Kobylianska](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olha_Kobylianska) (e.g. see [here](//books.google.com/books?id=bNcGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2+%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87+%D1%94%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%22)). There we also notice an interesting version for the female name *Євгенія* — *Генця*. However, as Olha Kobylianska wrote her diary mostly in German (with sporadic phrases in Ukrainian), it's unclear how she originally referred Yevhen Ozarkevych (maybe names were modified by translators).
  - Vasyl Baziv, “Хрест”, 2011:

    > — А як тебе звати, хлопче? — *Геньо*. Ну *Євген* називаюся.

  <sub>There are also novels where *Геньо* or *Ґеньо* is used as a character's name, but other versions of his name are never shown, e.g.: Anatolii Dnistrovyi, “Місто уповільненої дії”, 2003 (*Геньо*); Natalka Sniadanko, “Синдром стерильності”, 2006 (*Ґеньо*).</sub>

Comment: Непогано, але тут прийнято наводити джерела. Буде чудово, якщо Ви зможете знайти приклади використання цих варіантів в українській літературі (наприклад, [тут](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) чи [тут](//www.google.com/webhp?lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks)) або хоча б просто на інтернет-форумах — і доповнити відповідь.

Comment: А, перепрошую, іще одне: тут прийнято (за можливості) надавати відповіді тією мовою, якою поставлене запитання. Типу, якщо запитання українською, то краще українською, якщо запитання англійською, то краще англійською (бо запитувач теоретично може лише починати вивчати українську або взагалі не знати англійську). Але якщо знаєте відповідь і не можете відповісти тією ж мовою — то, звісно, краще відповісти як можете.

Comment: Геник або Ґеник?

Comment: Trying to save an answer.

Comment: Приєднуюся до підтримки скорочення Ґеник. На Покутті його використовують. До мого двоюрідного дідуся так звертаються.

Comment: @Sasha - I'm totally OK with Ukrainian - why it's indeed usually a case, nothing wrong with answering in Ukrainian if one who asks can understand in Ukrainian - I can and I guess I should have stated it clearly. 

A very nice answer!

Comment: @shabunc, yeah, I know that you know Ukrainian :). But IMHO it's a good practice in general: to prefer giving answers using the language of a question (if an answer writer can, of course). Because even if a question author knows both languages (surprisingly, not all of our visitors do) — it's not necessary that everyone who comes to the question from a search engine also knows both languages (i.e. one may be disappointed if he was attracted by a question in one language, but sees answers in another). IMHO.